# Does StringBuilder.substring(..) creates a new char[]?

Tags: java, android, string

After reading the android documentation about String, which includes this:

> This class is implemented using a char[]. The length of the array may
>   exceed the length of the string. For example, the string "Hello" may
>   be backed by the array ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'W'. 'o', 'r', 'l',
>   'd'] with offset 0 and length 5.
>
> Multiple strings can share the same char[] because strings are
>   immutable. The substring(int) method always returns a string that
>   shares the backing array of its source string. Generally this is an
>   optimization: fewer character arrays need to be allocated, and less
>   copying is necessary. But this can also lead to unwanted heap
>   retention. Taking a short substring of long string means that the long
>   shared char[] won't be garbage until both strings are garbage. This
>   typically happens when parsing small substrings out of a large input.
>   To avoid this where necessary, call new
>   String(longString.subString(...)). The string copy constructor always
>   ensures that the backing array is no larger than necessary.

So my question is : What happens when we create a String as the substring of a StringBuilder? Are there any memory considerations as well?
Which leads to my other question :
Is the combo StringBuilder / String a good choice when selecting small parts of a large text and programming with rapidity considerations in mind?

Thank you for your attention and your time, have a good day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here: [AbstractStringBuilder.substring(int, int)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#AbstractStringBuilder.substring%28int,int%29) (StringBuilder extends this class) in OpenJDK does exactly what's described in your snippet: creates a new String to avoid retaining the memory for the whole string substring was called on. Let us hope that Dalvik's implementation is the same :)

Actually, you get the idea how to check this, here are instructions on how to get Dalvik sources: http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

Comment: I went on

[link](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java.html)

to see the source code where we can see that the returned String is created this way :

 "return new String(value, start, end - start)"

Which according to the android documentation indeed leads to a new char[] being cretaed for this String.

Thank your for your help!